# What is AppProps in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am learning next.js. I found below code in `_app.tsx` file.

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

What is `AppProps` here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using typescript, so you must declare the type of arguments passed to a function

Your MyApp function is receiving `{ Component, pageProps }` object as argument. **AppProps** is the type of that object.

You can find out more if you right click AppProps and Go to definition